# Casting generic elements of collections with different types?

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have a class with a type parameter, `InfoTag<>`:

```
public abstract class InfoElement {}

public class InfoTag<T> : InfoElement
{
  public Func<string, T> Parser { get; set; }
  public string Terminator { get; set; }
  public char TypeChar { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a list of InfoTags:

```
List<InfoElement> tagSet = new()
{
  new InfoTag<bool>() { Parser = bool.Parse, Terminator = "\r", TypeChar = '?' },
  new InfoTag<string>() { Parser = x => x, Terminator = "\r#;", TypeChar = ';' },
//etc...
};
```

Iterating through the list returns `InfoElements`, but they need to be `InfoTags`.

```
foreach (InfoElement element in tagSet)
{
  var tag = ???;
  //do something...
}
```

Using `var tag = element as InfoTag<dynamic>` or `var tag = element as InfoTag<object>` just return null.
**How would I cast `element` to be an `InfoTag<>` with the correct generic parameter?**

Comment: An `InfoTag<bool>` is an `InfoTag<bool>`, not an `InfoTag<dynamic>` or an `InfoTag<object>`. You can't cast something as a type it isn't already. Casting is not magic. You would have to use `as InfoTag<bool>` and, if that's `null`, use `as InfoTag<object>` and so on. You could also use pattern matching, but I'll let you look into that if you want to.

Comment: You cannot cast to the "correct" generic type if you don't know which it is at compile time. There are several solutions for this, but it depends on what you're trying to do in your loop.

Comment: With this kind of stuff, it's best to not use generics.